# Trying to install SSL certificate on AWS Windows EC2 server without ELB. How to do that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, godaddy-api

I have purchased SSL certificate from Godaddy, and I am using AWS windows VM. Traffic on my site is not that much, so I can't spend additional charge on ELB. I want to install godaddy SSL certificate on my AWS windows server and get connected to the Godaddy site over https.

Comment: Did you follow detailed instruction on [godady](https://au.godaddy.com/help/request-my-ssl-certificate-and-learn-how-to-install-it-if-youre-new-to-ssls-start-here-32151)?

Comment: There is no direct docs from Godaddy for Windows VM without ELB. Godaddy has given instructions using ELB. No instructions from AWS server as well.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479534/aws-ssl-on-ec2-instance-without-load-balancer-nodejs